# DRF serializes datetime differently in the GET response vs POST response

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-rest-framework

```
class Event(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()

class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bar = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'start_date', 'end_date')
```

It works all fine and dandy:

```
GET .../api/v1/Event/
{
"count":23,
"next":null,
"previous":null,
"results":[{
   "databaseId":101488,
   "start_date":"2013-11-01T09:46:25",
   "end_date":"2013-11-02T09:46:25"
},...
]}
```

Now when I create a new event:

```
POST /api/v1/Event/
{
   "start_date":"2013-11-03T09:46:25",
   "end_date":"2013-11-04T09:46:25"
}
```

In the JSON response I get:

```
{
   "databaseId":101489,
   "start_date":"2013-11-03T09:46:25.250000",
   "end_date":"2013-11-04T09:46:25.750000"
}
```

So I get back a more precise format. I'd like to get back exactly the same format, so the client developer won't have to write different parser codes.

I'm using Python 2.7, DRF 3.1.3, Django 1.4.21 (I know it's old but it's a large codebase, one day we'll migrate).

Comment: ISO8601 standard allows for any number of decimals of precision.  Any parser should be able to handle that - though it's very odd that your data somehow came back with extra time added (250 ms on `start_date`, 750 ms on `end_date`).  It should have just been zeros.

Comment: I tried your code and get same post data as JSON response. What did you setup on the TIME_ZONE in the settings file?

Comment: I see `TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'` in `settings.py`. One more thing which might be important, another skeleton in the closet (besides Django 1.4): our application doesn't use TZ, meaning `USE_TZ=False`. Ouch!

Comment: I Set USE_TZ=True in my settings.py

Comment: I just tried explicitly specifying format format for DateTimeField. This would be a lot of unnecessary (supposedly) plumbing code, since I would have to explicitly spell out any DateTimeField I have (I have many dozens of models I expose with who knows how many DateTime field). So I added `start_date=serializers.DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` and that yielded the format I want.

Comment: So I'm looking for some global setting. Btw, `start_date=serializers.DateTimeField(format='iso-8859-1')` didn't work. It gave me back the date time string "iso-8859-1" :D

Comment: I also tried `start_date=serializers.DateTimeField(format=None)`, which would be equal for that field with the `REST_FRAMEWORK = { 'DATETIME_FORMAT': None }` global setting. Maybe I'll try to set there an strftime format instead of "iso-8859-1" they mention. If that works that'd be sweet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I couldn't figure out what causes this, but explicitly enforcing format string helps:

```
start_date=serializers.DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```